# What is the best way to update the webpage only when a new entry is saved in the database?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am wondering what will be the best way to update the webpage only when a new entry is saved in the database?

For example, suppose one of my visitor is reading a post on my blog. At the same time some other visitor comments on that particular blog post. Then I want that latest comment to appear on that page without reloading the page.

I know the technology used here will be `AJAX/jQuery` but will I have to run the AJAX continuously every time using something `setTimeout()`?

If I do so, then it will generate a lot of http request endlessly. Is it possible that AJAX runs only when it is needed indeed and not all the time?

Comment: Polling AJAX is one solution, but it's ugly and doesn't scale well, so you may end up DDOS'ing your own server. I'd use websockets instead.

Comment: You are looking at the difference between polling and interrupt. Using Ajax in a continuous setTimeout loop is very easy to do. It is polling. Polling uses a lot of resources. An interrupt will be triggered by the server when needed. But, how do you get the server to send a message to the web browser? The browser is a client, not a server. It isn't listening. You need to keep the HTTP connection open with javascripted sockets all the time to listen for the interrupt message. So, either way, you will have HTTP overhead.

Comment: have a look at socket.io or socketo.me

Comment: but ajax polling will continuously request server for response. is it not possible it fires only when it is needed?